# Enabling ArcSDE Archiving with Python and C API using ArcGIS 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, archiving

I have a script that  does some register as versioned and updating privileges.

How would I call into the c api for ArcSDE to enable archiving with python?

http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/capi/versioning/archcreate.htm

Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this was available earlier than **ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop**, but there is now a tool called **[Enable Archiving (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000018t000000)** which:

> Enables archiving on a table, feature layer, or feature dataset.

Its online documentation, which is linked above, provides an ArcPy code sample that:

> illustrates how to use the EnableArchiving tool in a stand-alone
>   script.